# cURL Stopped working after a few requests

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to build up some data from this website, i did around 50 requests and then the script stopped working and i can't figure out why, maybe the sites blocked my IP or something ?

If i run the script from another IP it works.

Is there anyway to still scrape data from a site if it has blocked me?

this is the curl function im using

```
function doMagic($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init();

  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Pragma: ";

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://ds-scene.net");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
  $html = curl_exec($curl);
  echo 'Curl error: '. curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  return $html;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to set `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);` and see if `curl_error()` returns anything.

Comment: Curl error: Operation timed out after 30003 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting any response after a certain amount requests, then its confirmed that they are not liking any repeated requests from you. So you should better stop hitting them(if you do not have permission to run spider on their site). You can continue by binding with new IP(`CURLOPT_INTERFACE`), or using proxy(`CURLOPT_PROXY`), or even by slowing down the request amount. But still, its not legal, especially when you do not have permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think its apache timeout increase execution time of script.
use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` at top of your script
it worked for me. Cheers.